# Not able to get the json array length in Karate

Tags: karate

Can anybody help?api.store.book[*].author :is not returning any values .Even the length function api.length() is not working .But , api.store.book[0]:returns the details  .Below is the reference json

```
*def api = read('book.json')
    
    {
        "store": {
            "book": [
                {
                    "category": "reference",
                    "author": "Nigel Rees",
                    "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                    "price": 8.95
                },
                {
                    "category": "fiction",
                    "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                    "title": "Sword of Honour",
                    "price": 12.99
                }]}}
```

Comment: `* def authors = karate.jsonPath(api, "$.store.book[*].author")` seems working

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get-short-cut

```
* def authors = $api.store.book[*].author
* print authors
```